# Fetching user data from sessions | Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in:

Tags: php, sql, fetch

To make it as brief as possible:

I'm trying to make a profile page where a user should get an overview of their own data. I therefore try to execute the following code in order to do so:

```
            <?php

            try {
                $q = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_first_name = '{$_SESSION['user_first_name']}'");
                $q->execute();
                $users = $q->fetch();

                foreach ($users as $user) {

            ?>

                    <div class="user">
                        <div>First name: <b><?= $user['user_first_name'] ?></b></div>
                        <div>Last name: <b><?= $user['user_last_name'] ?></b></div>
                        <div>Phone: <b><?= $user['user_phone'] ?></b></div>
                        <div>Email: <b><?= $user['user_email'] ?></b></div>
                        <div>User Id: <b><?= $user['user_id'] ?></b></div>
                    </div>


            <?php
                }
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                _res(500, ['info' => 'system under maintainance', 'error' => __LINE__]);
            }

            ?>
```

When testing the page I receive the following error: *Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in: file, line, etc.*

According (at least from what I understand) to this error I'm trying to access the index of a string which obviously isn't possible... but I'm wrapping my session into an associative array which leaves me wondering where I'm off.

I'd appreciate any help coming my way.

Comment: try to use `fetchAll` instead.

Comment: @Faesal

Tried to do so earlier too. When I use FetchAll() I get every the data from ALL users. Yikes.

Comment: Try to use: `$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`